# Differences between space and > selector

Tags: html, css

What is the diffrence betwen selector 6 and 7 from [w3](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

The title says all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `>` is known as the **[`child combinator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)** and it selects children that are **direct** descendants.

A `space` between selectors indicates that the second selector must be a child of the first, but does **not** need to be a direct child (meaning a grandchild would qualify).

This can be seen in the following:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}

.outer > .middle {
  background: green; /* Applied */
}

.outer .inner {
  background: red; /* Applied */
}

.outer > .inner {
  background: blue; /* Not applied */
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```